# Existence proof of a vector in $\Bbb R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Consider a linear transformation $\mathsf T$ from $\Bbb R^3$ to $\Bbb R$. Show that there exists a vector $\vec v$ in $\Bbb R^3$ such that $\mathsf T(\vec x)$ = $\vec v \cdot \vec x$, for all $\vec x$ in $\Bbb R^3$.

I don't understand how the dot product is a linear transformation considering that the output is a scalar. And I have no idea how to prove this.Can someone shed some light for me.

Comment: The end result of the dot product is a scalar.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Riesz Representation Theorem in linear algebra](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1738045/riesz-representation-theorem-in-linear-algebra)

Answer (score 1):

Consider the vector $\vec v=(T(\vec{e_1}),T(\vec{e_2}),T(\vec{e_3}))$

Answer (score 1):

Let ${\mathsf T}(\vec e_1)=a$, ${\mathsf T}(\vec e_2)=b$, and ${\mathsf T}(\vec e_3)=c$, then by setting $\vec v=(a,b,c)$, we see that for any
$\vec x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in\mathbb{R}^3$, 
\begin{align}
{\mathsf T}(\vec x)
&={\mathsf T}(x_1\vec e_1+x_2\vec e_2+x_3\vec e_3)\\
&=x_1{\mathsf T}(\vec e_1)+x_2{\mathsf T}(\vec e_2)+x_3{\mathsf T}(\vec e_3)\\
&=a\,x_1+b\,x_2+c\,x_3\\
&=\vec v\cdot\vec x.
\end{align}
This completes the proof.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the zero transformation function as $T: \mathbb{R^3} \rightarrow{} \mathbb{R}$. Then it is trivial that
$$T(\vec{x}) = \vec{0} \cdot \vec{x}$$