# Riesz Representation Theorem in Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, riesz-representation-theorem

Let $\mathbb{V}$ be a finite dimensional inner product space and $\alpha : \mathbb{V} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a linear functional. Prove that there is a unique vector $\overrightarrow v_{0} \in \mathbb{V}$ such that $\alpha(\overrightarrow v)=\langle\overrightarrow v,\overrightarrow v_{0}\rangle$ for all $\overrightarrow v \in \mathbb{V}$.

**My approach**:

I suppose that there is exists another vector $\overrightarrow w_{0} \in \mathbb{V}$ that satisfies the same property. We get $\langle\overrightarrow v,\overrightarrow v_{0}-\overrightarrow w_{0}\rangle=0$ and I need to show that $\overrightarrow v_{0}=\overrightarrow w_{0}$ somehow. Any tips on how to do that? I tried taking an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{V}$ but that didn't help in the end.

Comment: What if you set $v=\vec{v}_0-\vec{w}_0$?

Comment: This will show uniqueness, but you still have show existence.  That will actually follow from uniqueness and finite-dimensionality.

Comment: @fred, according to the answer given below, proving uniqueness seems to be a simple implication. Any tips on how to show existence? I did not see that part of the question for some reason.

Comment: @fred, Any tips on how to show existence?

Comment: @fred, attempt of mine: I can create a basis for V with $n<\infty$ dimensions. Therefore I can use the linear extension theorem: that $\exists$ a linear transformation $\alpha$ and we define $\alpha(v)=<v,v_{0}$ which is possible since inner products pertain to the vector space \mathbb{R}?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You get

$$\langle v,\,v_0-w_0\rangle=0\;\;\color{red}{\forall\,v\in V}\iff v_0-w_0=0$$

as zero is *the only* vector which is orthogonal to the whole space.

**Existence** Choose an orthonormal basis $\;\{u_1,...,u_n\}\;$ of $\;V\;$ , and let

$$v_0:=\sum_{k=1}^n\alpha(u_k)u_k\in V\;\;\implies\;\;\forall\,v=\sum_{i=1}^n a_iu_i\in V:$$

$$\langle v_0,v\rangle=\sum_{i,k=1}^n\alpha(u_k)a_i\langle u_k,u_i\rangle=\sum_{k=1}^n\alpha(u_k)a_k\stackrel{\text{linearity of}\;\alpha}=\alpha\left(\sum_{k=1}^n a_ku_k\right)=\alpha(v)$$

Comment: I've actually never seen that property. Can there be no other vector orthogonal to the whole space? If $\mathbb{V}$ is a plane we can always find a vector orthogonal to the whole plane in that case, so doesn't that disprove what you just wrote?

Comment: @Sadem It follows at once from $\;\langle v,v\rangle=0\iff v=0\;$, which is one of the axioms defining inner product in a linear space. And pay attention to what I wrote: the only vector orthogonal **to the whole space** is the zero vector. Of course subspaces can have non-zero orthogonal vectors, and in fact they're pretty important.

Comment: but $\overrightarrow v\not = \overrightarrow v_{0}-\overrightarrow w_{0}$, so you can't apply that property can you?

Comment: @Sadem Choose $\;v=v_0-w_0\;$ !! You can because the equality is true **for all** $\;v\in V\;$ ?

Comment: I'm sorry I am kind of lost bear with me. Wouldn't choosing $v=v_{0}-w_{0}$ contradict the fact that we want the equality to be true for all $v$?

Edit: I understand now, the uniqueness part should come after the existence part and the existence part says that the equation is true for all $v\in \mathbb{V}$. Thanks for your help. Any tips on how to show existence?

Comment: @Sadem Look at the addition to my answer now.

Comment: @Joanpemo I think you might have a typo in the first line in the existence part.

Comment: @fred Thank you, but I can't see it. Would you be so kind to tell what exactly?

Comment: @Joanpemo, I guess I don't understand it.  $v_0$ is the thing we are trying to find, right?  How does $v_0\in V$  imply the thing on the other side of the arrow?  I think you might need to change the duality pairing on the next line to $\langle v_0,w\rangle$ from $\langle v,w\rangle$.  I just couldn't follow it.  Thanks.

Comment: @fred Thank you, now I see the typo but in the *second line*: it should be $\;\langle v_0,v\rangle\;$ , not $\;\langle v,w\rangle\;$ .